# How pass payload to urlfetch "DELETE" method?

Tags: rest, curl, webapp2, restful-url, urlfetch

I'm trying to pass payload to "DELETE" method to urlfetch, I've seen in doc that the "DELETE" method don't support payload and I don't understand why.
If I have a resource in my API that have implemented the  "delete" method to delete a resource, I dont understand why not is posible pass payload to this method with urlfetch.

This is the code of request:

```
form_fields = {"dni": request.dni}
form_data = urllib.urlencode(form_fields)
result = urlfetch.fetch(url=url, payload=form_data, method=urlfetch.DELETE)
```

And this is a extract to my API:

```
class Alumnos(webapp2.RequestHandler):
   ...
   def delete(self):
   ...
   self.request.get('dni')
   ...
```

I would like that this works like work for example when I call to API with a curl:

```
 curl -d "dni=uu" -X DELETE  -G http://localhost:8002/alumnos
```

Somebody have any Idea to how use the same "delete" method  with urlfetch to pass payload without have to use finally other method like "post" or other?

Thanks you so much!

Comment: that curl line doesn't send the data in the body, the `-G` you use makes curl put dni=uu at the end of the URL. Use `--trace-ascii` to see all details in what curl sends and receives.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I know better now. But, anyway, do you know any way to make it work with urlfetch?